# How can I center the menu on my WordPress site?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to get the menu on my WordPress site to align center.

I tried a bunch of things, including pulling out the float: left; CSS entry, but it won't work.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `float: left;` style and add this style:

```
ul#top-menu {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 425px; /*the menu width*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `#top-menu` an explicit width `width: 450px` and `margin: 23px auto 0 auto`;

Get rid of the `float: left`.

Alternatively, make the `li` elements inline blocks `display: inline-block` and use `text-align: center` on their parent.

Comment: Is that the same as the above posted answer?

Comment: I did try the text-align: center thing, but it didn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

```
ul#top-menu { margin-top: 23px;  font-weight: bold; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 420px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about margin-left: 30%;? Just adjust it to be exactly centered...